# Downloading from Maven central failed

Tags: java, windows, azure, maven, code-completion

i unable to compile my code, during compilation maven unable to download maven dependencies

````
2021-03-03T01:24:14.1723674Z [command]C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C "F:\agentutility\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin\mvn.cmd -version"
2021-03-03T01:24:15.4994355Z Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
2021-03-03T01:24:15.5059973Z Maven home: F:\agentutility\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin\..
2021-03-03T01:24:15.5060933Z Java version: 15.0.2, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jdk-15.0.2
2021-03-03T01:24:15.5061416Z Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
2021-03-03T01:24:15.5069929Z OS name: "windows server 2019", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
2021-03-03T01:24:15.5489927Z [command]C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C "F:\agentutility\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin\mvn.cmd -f C:\myaagent2\_work\7\s\solution\core\build\maven\pom.xml help:effective-pom"
2021-03-03T01:29:35.4252788Z [INFO] Scanning for projects...
2021-03-03T01:29:35.4253062Z [WARNING] 
---
2021-03-03T01:29:35.4260206Z Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/3.1/maven-compiler-plugin-3.1.pom
2021-03-03T01:29:35.4260314Z [WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.1
---
2021-03-03T01:29:35.4263768Z Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
2021-03-03T01:29:35.4263829Z Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
---
2021-03-03T01:29:58.9762348Z [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
2021-03-03T01:29:58.9765107Z [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2021-03-03T01:29:58.9766283Z [ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin:3.0.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin:jar:3.0.1: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin:pom:3.0.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-source-plugin/3.0.1/maven-source-plugin-3.0.1.pom ProxyInfo{host='10.218.129.49', userName='null', port=443, type='https', nonProxyHosts='null'}: Connect to 10.218.129.49:443 [/10.218.129.49] failed: Connection timed out: connect -> [Help 1]
2021-03-03T01:29:58.9766382Z [ERROR]```
````

Answer (score 0):

@Satyam Pandey, please below line

> 2021-03-03T01:29:58.9766283Z [ERROR] Plugin
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin:3.0.1 or one of its
> dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
> for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin:jar:3.0.1: Could not
> transfer artifact
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin:pom:3.0.1 from/to central
> (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Transfer failed for
> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-source-plugin/3.0.1/maven-source-plugin-3.0.1.pom
> **ProxyInfo{host='10.218.129.49', userName='null', port=443,
> type='https', nonProxyHosts='null'}: Connect to 10.218.129.49:443
> [/10.218.129.49] failed: Connection timed out: connect -> [Help 1]
> 2021-03-03T01:29:58.9766382Z [ERROR]**

Clearly, there is a connection issue please try with basic sanity test such ping the IP
and telnet 10.218.129.49 443

Seem like ur ar using proxy, please make sure ur configuring rite forward proxy from ur end

Comment: also if sanity working fine, please run with -X mode in maven it will more debug and paste here I can help further.